# How to upgrade a package in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If I have a package installed, that has built-in documentation, and I want to install an updated version of the same package, is it safe just to erase the old version folder?

Last time I tried, I got some error messages on the documentation, but never understood if the problem came from this fact. Is there an “uninstall package” procedure?

Thank you,
Pedro

Answer (score 1):

If the package has an installer, you should see if it has a corresponding uninstall mode. Otherwise, simple deletion should be safe.

If you do run into any errors, feel free to update your question.